# NPV of getting 100 $ per year, for 10 years, 5 %

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the NPV of getting 100 $ per year, for 10 years, if the bank gives you 5%?

The book says

$\frac{1-1.05^{-10}}{0.05}$

But, according the formula of geometric sums, with $k = 1.05^{-1}$ I get $$\frac{\left( 1.05^{-1} \right)^{10}-1}{1.05^{-1}-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

From the formula about NPV, we have

$$\text{NPV}=\frac{100}{1+r}+\frac{100}{(1+r)^2}+\cdots+\frac{100}{(1+r)^{10}}=100\cdot\frac{(1+r)^{-1}-(1+r)^{-11}}{1-(1+r)^{-1}}$$$$=100\cdot\frac{1-(1+r)^{-10}}{(1+r)-1}=100\cdot\frac{1-(1+r)^{-10}}{r}.$$

In your question, $r=0.05$. So, we have
$$\text{NPV}=100\cdot\frac{1-(1.05)^{-10}}{0.05}.$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: What do you do in the second $=$ ? (where you write = 100 etc.)

Also, I should get the correct answer with a the formula of geometric series 

$$a + ar + a r^2 + a r^3 + \cdots + a r^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k= a \, \frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r} = a\frac{r^{n}-1}{r-1} $$

Comment: First, you forgot to write $a$ in the last of your formula in your comment. Second, I used the formula in your comment. The equal ratio of our geometric progression is $(1+r)^{-1}$ without the initial term.

Comment: @jacob: I added a bit.